# Проблема с Instantiate-ом в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Unity на сцене есть игровой объект - имитирующий зеркало.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот его код:

```
public class MirrorS : MonoBehaviour {
public Camera MCamera;
public int TextureSize = 500;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Awake()
{
    MCamera.targetTexture.width = TextureSize;
    MCamera.targetTexture.height = TextureSize;
}

private void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    MCamera.enabled = false;
}
private void OnBecameVisible()
{
    MCamera.enabled = true;
}
```

}

Если вкратце - мне необходимо создавать копии этого зеркала.

Примерно так:

```
 class ParticleData
{
  public  ParticleData(Vector3 position, float rotation )
    {


        Instantiate(InstObject, position, new Quaternion(rotation, rotation, rotation, rotation));

    }

}
```

Где `InstObject` - это ссылка на нужный объект.

```
 List<Particle> Particles = new List<Particle>(10);
```

Причем Экземпляры `ParticleData` создаю в цикле: - если нажата левая кнопка мыши и i=10 -т.е каждый десятый

```
for (int i = 0; i <= MainEmit.particleCount; i++)
        {
    if (i == Particles.ToArray().Length && Input.GetButton("Fire1")) 
            {
              P = new Particle();
                int EmitParticle = Particles.LastIndexOf( P, i);//10
                MainEmit.Emit(EmitParticle); //испускаем последнюю частицу из списка
                float ParticleLifeTime = Recalculate(P).GetEnumerator().Current;

                              data = new ParticleData(P.position = new Vector3(P.position.x + Particle_v + ParticleLifeTime, P.position.y + Particle_v + ParticleLifeTime, P.position.z + Particle_v + ParticleLifeTime), P.rotation);

            }
```

Но при создании копии этого объекта - происходит ошибка:

> Setting width of already created render texture is not supported!
>   UnityEngine.RenderTexture:set_width(Int32)
>   MirrorS:Awake() (at Assets/MirrorS.cs:16)
>   UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(Object, Vector3, Quaternion)
>   ParticleData:.ctor(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/particleSystemEmiter.cs:89)
>   particleSystemEmiter:Update() (at Assets/particleSystemEmiter.cs:37)
>
> Setting height of already created render texture is not supported!
>   UnityEngine.RenderTexture:set_height(Int32)
>   MirrorS:Awake() (at Assets/MirrorS.cs:17)
>   UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(Object, Vector3, Quaternion)
>   ParticleData:.ctor(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/particleSystemEmiter.cs:89)
>   particleSystemEmiter:Update() (at Assets/particleSystemEmiter.cs:37)

т.е оно как бы не может присвоить ту же ширину и высоту текстуры новосоздаваемому объекту?

Но ведь TextureSize  - это можно сказать что "константа" при создании объекта? - как при следующем Instantiate - с ним могут возникать проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, для каждого зеркала нужна своя камера со своей renderTexture, а ты все в одной меняешь. Затем, если renderTexture уже создалась, то поменять ей размеры уже нельзя. Только сделав Release и new RenderTexture.